# rfkill cannot open /dev/rfkill permission denied ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, drivers, permissions, bluetooth

After a night of messing with `rfkill` to solve issues simultaneously by purging bluetooth to fix WiFi(RTL8221CE) interruptions. Some configs were changed, now at boot it says and I am not quoting:

> rfkill cannot open /dev/rfkill permission denied, fix as soon as feasible..

`rfkill list bluetooth` shows nothing while,

`sudo systemctl status bluetooth` shows **inactive(dead)**, couldn't turn it on anymore.

bluez gui is also unable to start saying no drivers detected, after reinstalling it, it no longer shows in menu and neither does `bluez` command run anything.

Question : How can we both fix the rfkill alert and turn Bluetooth back on ?.

Edit : These are the commands we used before the issue arose,

`sudo gedit /etc/bluetooth/main.conf`

`sudo systemctl disable bluetooth.service`

`echo "rfkill block bluetooth" >> ~/.profile`

`gsettings set org.blueman.plugins.powermanager auto-power-on false`

`sudo rfkill block bluetooth`

`Disabling power-save settings`

Comment: It is unclear what you man by "messing with rfkill". You need to revert what you did.

Comment: @Pilot6 unfortunately, we don't remember !

Comment: Then reinstall the system. We can't guess that either.

Comment: @Pilot6 there's not enough time, the answer is updated with the recent commands.